# Jboss with jms queue on standalone Hornetq machine

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

I have 2 machines:
1. Jboss 5 ( application ) 
2. Hornetq ( jms queue )

How i must configure jboss and hornet to cooperate?
I wish to have jms queue on diffrent machine.

Answer (score 0):

On your HonetQ machine, you'll need some way to interact with the local HornetQ install. You might want to look at the Stomp connector for this purpose. Binding the stomp connector to the local interface and communicating with it through a simple socket is an easy way of sending messages to your local HornetQ. Now to get your message forwarded to/from your local instance of HornetQ to your server will require a "bridge" configuration on both machine (1) and (2).

This setup is well documented in the HornetQ documentation. Once this is setup you can also do some cool stuff with durable queues and spooling of messages on your remote machine when network connectivity is unavailable.

Rick